# importing a js library throws this undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying every variation but I don't understand why I can't include this library: [jkanban.js](https://github.com/riktar/jkanban/blob/master/jkanban.js)

```
<template>
  <div id="kanban"></div>
</template>

<script>

import jKanban from '../components/jkanban.js'

export default {

}

</script>
```

I get the error in the console:

> Cannot set property 'jKanban' of undefined

After looking closely, I can see **this** is **undefined**.

This works fine without vue so I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Internally, that library is doing the following:

```
(function () {

    this.jKanban = function () {
        var self = this;
...
```

Comment: the library in question is https://github.com/riktar/jkanban/blob/master/jkanban.js

Comment: It looks you imported "jkanban", but property is "jKanban". Check typos

Comment: I'm afraid it is not a typo. the problem is the library is setting this.jKanban and "this" is undefined

Comment: is the library exporting what you want to import?

Comment: If you change this keyword with window may it works as expected.
window.jKanban

Comment: that got rid of that error but then failed later. I think it is due to ES6 something I'm not too familiar with

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I did (it's from a Vue 3 project but should work for React, older Vue, etc.)...

From the source code (https://github.com/riktar/jkanban) *copy* the `jkanban.js` file from the root source folder (NOT from the `dist` folder - which includes the code for the *dragula* libray plus a bunch of stuff to support `require` as far as I can tell) into a folder in your *own* project.

Add the dragula library: `npm install dragula`.

Then some code edits. For some reason, the dragula libray keeps throwing because there's no `global` object, so I tried adding this: `const gobal = window;`  (in a script tag in the index.html but I guess it could go elsewhere.)

I also edited the to the jKanban.js file, at the top:

```
import dragula from "dragula";  // change from require

const jKanban = function () {
    var self = this
    var __DEFAULT_ITEM_HANDLE_OPTIONS = {
   // etc. etc...
```

And at the bottom:

```
    //init plugin
    this.init()
}

export default jKanban; // export it
```

And after all that, I was able to import it and use it in a component:

```
import jKanban from "@/stuff/jkanban.js";
// ...stuff
const kanban = new jKanban(someOptionsIPreparedEarlier);
```

You'll also need to include the CSS file of course.  And if there are any updates to the library, you'll need to pull them in manually.

:o)